# Call function in ejs and return mysql data

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a ejs like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
    <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is great</h1>
        <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
        <% rows.forEach(function (rows) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= rows.tag %>
                <div>
                    <%
                        var contents = egallery.getContents(rows.tag)
                    %>
                    <%= JSON.stringify(contents) %>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <%- include('../partials/footer'); %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and a custom js calling mysql and return data

```
var conn = require('./conn.js');
conn.connect();

function getTags () {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        conn.query(
            "Select distinct tag from ray_url",
            (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                }
                return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result)
            }
        )
    })

    /*conn.end();*/

}

function getContents (tag) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        conn.query(
            "Select * from ray_url where tag = ?",
            [tag],
            (err, result) => {
                //if (err) {
                    console.log(result);  //i saw data
                    console.log(err);
                    //throw err;
                //}
                return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result)
            }
        )
    })
}



module.exports = {
    getTags : getTags,
    getContents : getContents
};
```

i saw the data was printed, but the line var contents = egallery.getContents(rows.tag) , the contents is blank, any one know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Putting data fetching logic in an EJS template is not recommended. The view layer violates the SRP which reduces maintainability, and readability. In addition, we can't use JS syntax highlighting, formatting, and intelligent analysis of code editor.

The better way is to fetch, transform and assemble the data in the controller(the best place is the data layer).

E.g.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, './views'));

function getContents(tag) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // simulate query data from database
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ result: `content for tag: ${tag}` });
        }, 1000);
    });
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const rows = [{ tag: 'a' }, { tag: 'b' }];
    const rowsWithContents = await Promise.all(
        rows.map((r) => getContents(r.tag).then((content) => ({ ...r, content }))),
    );
    console.log(rowsWithContents);
    res.render('index', { rows: rowsWithContents });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server listens on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

`index.ejs`:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
                <% rows.forEach(function (row) { %>
                    <%= row.tag %>
                    <div>
                        <%= row.content.result %>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
                
          a
          <div>
              content for tag: a
          </div>
                
          b
          <div>
              content for tag: b
          </div>
                
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```